# SignalR hangs on IIS or website page - when more than 10 Clients access website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, websocket, signalr, chat

We have a portal Build on ASP.NET MVC 4.NetFramework and for chat communication, we are using SignalR jquery.signalR-2.4.3.js

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.3.min.js"></script>
        @*<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>*@
        <script src="~/Scripts/signalr/hub.js"></script>



  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                            console.log("Started SignalR");
                            chat.server.setConnectionID($.connection.hub.id, parseInt($("#hUserID").val()));

                        });
```

The above script reference and code are used to start signalR connection
for multiple tabs open and disconnect the SignalR, We used to broadcast as below
which works, but we are facing issues with the different devices of more than 10 Users.

```
   const bc = new BroadcastChannel("my-awesome-site");

                bc.onmessage = (event) => {
                    debugger
                    if (event.data === `Other Disconnect Please`) {
                        //bc.postMessage(`No you're not.`);
                        console.log(`Another tab of this site just got opened`);
                        $.connection.hub.stop().done(function () {
                            console.log("closed signalr");
                        });
                            
                        //isAnotherTabLoaded = true;
                    }
                   
                    
                    //if (event.data === `No you're not.`) {
                    //    console.log(`An instance of this site is already running`);
                    //    isAnotherTabLoaded = true;
                    //}
                
                };

                bc.postMessage(`Other Disconnect Please`);
```

in startup.cs we have this confirguration

```
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            //hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = false;
            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            //app.MapSignalR();

        }
```

In hub we have below code

```
 public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {


        string fromUserSRId = "";
        string toUserSRId = "";
        DateTime chatMsgDatetime;
      
        //Sets connection with staffa and signalR id
        public async Task setConnectionID(string connectionID, int userid)
        {
            //... Extra Business logic
            response.loginhistorylist = ConstantDictionaryVM.signalConnectionList;
            await Clients.Client(connectionID).successConnection(response);
            //await Clients.Caller.getChatStaffList(result.response);
        }



    }
```

To access more than 10 users we have to close 2 users than other 1 user get the page loaded,

if we remove signalR we are able to open the site on 20+ machines.

IIS WebSocket Configuration is done as below

[image]

IIS and OS info

[image]

It would be a big help is someone can give us a solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's the machine you use? Windows 10 or 11 is not qualified for load testing, as they both have 10 concurrent connection limit.

Comment: Win 10 Pro, Just added image of the Configuration above
thanks , i will check with Windows Server OS , and get back

Comment: Win 10 Pro also has a maximum of 10 concurrent connections limit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions. It is recommended that you use Windows Server OS or IIS express for testing. Windows Server OS doesn't have these request restrictions.